# When I export my java game from eclipse it crashes with a IllegalArgumentException input == null

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a Java game with some friends of mine and want to be able to export to a jar so they can play it and test it.
But when I export the jar it crashes with this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.EnderVizion.game.Game.<init>(Game.java:46)
    at com.EnderVizion.game.Game.main(Game.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at com.EnderVizion.game.level.SpawnLevel.loadLevel(SpawnLevel.java:16)
    at com.EnderVizion.game.level.Level.<init>(Level.java:26)
    at com.EnderVizion.game.level.SpawnLevel.<init>(SpawnLevel.java:11)
    at com.EnderVizion.game.graphics.Screen.<clinit>(Screen.java:14)
    ... 2 more
```

My code is located at [CODE](http://github.com/LukeJansen/game)

Comment: Post the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Going to need a bit more to go with this, but my inkling is that you're trying to load an image from a specific location relative to your source code in your development framework, and your JAR can't find it due to the folder structure being different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code here isn't finding this image:

```
 public static Level spawn = new SpawnLevel("/levels/SpawnWorld.png");
```

did your image folder "levels" get exported with the jar?

Comment: I realised that I didnt add it to build path correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
this.icon = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("source/test.png"));
```

where source folder is present at the same level as your src folder. Make sure you have test.png file inside source folder (In your project structure)